# Fold Expression template argument deduction/substitution failed

Tags: c++, c++17

Trying to Learn fold expression .Getting error for argument deduction failed

```
#include<iostream>

template <typename T>
struct sum{
    T value;
    template <typename ... Ts>
    sum(Ts&&...values) : value{(values + ...)}{}//error here
};
int main()
{
    sum s(2,3,4);
}
```

Error

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:11:16: error: class template argument deduction failed:
     sum s(2,3,4);
                ^
main.cpp:11:16: error: no matching function for call to 'sum(int, int, int)'
main.cpp:7:5: note: candidate: template<class T, class ... Ts> sum(Ts&& ...)-> sum<T>
     sum(Ts&&...values) : value{(values + ...)}{}
     ^~~
main.cpp:7:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:11:16: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
     sum s(2,3,4);
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6a580a7bbf02e1bd)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: The question is about fold-expressions, but nothing in the compiler error even points to it. Your first step should always be to try to simplify - in this case, removing the fold-expression [still fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21d3d2a2d722c0b2) the same way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not about fold expressions. The compiler is complaining because it has no way to deduce the `typename T`.

To solve that, you could provide a [deduction guide](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides) after the class definiton, like so:

```
template <typename ...P> sum(P &&... p) -> sum<decltype((p + ...))>;
```

Alternatively, you could manually specify the argument: `sum<int> s(2,3,4);`

---

*But* I'd rather make `sum` a function. What's the point of making it a class anyway?

```
template <typename ...P> auto sum (P &&... p)
{
    return (p + ...);
}
```

Comment: template <typename T>
struct sum{
    T value;
    template <typename ... Ts>
    sum(Ts&&...values) : value{(values + ...)}{}
};
template <typename ...P> sum(P &&...) -> sum<decltype((std::declval<P>() + ...))>;   //error C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations

Comment: @HariomSingh [No repro.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0b5f3f84e682ba5) What compiler and version? You either have to upgrade the compiler or use other solutions.

Comment: xcode 9  beta c++17 ..Thanks for the link it works only on the link .Looks like problem is with xcode

Comment: @HariomSingh That's not a compiler, that's an IDE. It could use different compilers under the hood. But I just tried to compile it with the latest clang (4.0.0), and got the exact same error. Looks like it doesn't support deduction guides yet. Unless you want to install GCC, you have to do `sum<int> s(blah);`.

Comment: //:configuration = Debug
CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = c++17
//:configuration = Release
CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = c++17
//:completeSettings = some
CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD

Comment: I'm still new at deduction guides, so can you tell me why you chose `sum(P &&... p)` instead of `sum(P...)`

Comment: @AndyG I'm as new at them as you, if not worse. There is no real reason, I just copied it from the constructor.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Nevermind, it makes sense now. In my head I transformed `P&&...p` into another fold expression haha.

Comment: @AndyG Haha, ok. :P